# Meme (title with picture) exchanger

Tags: java, mvc, database, spring

Project structure without code:
[image: project structure without code]

Packages:

[image: packages]

Classes in packages:

[image: first part]
[image: second part]

In `ConfigConstants` I store path to folder, where I save pictures. Also in `WebConstants` I store URL of Servlet.
Here is mySQL script for creating db:

```
drop database meme_exchanger;
CREATE SCHEMA `meme_exchanger` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;

use meme_exchanger;

create table users(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(30) not null unique,
    password varchar(20) not null,
    access_level_id int references access_levels.id,
    creation_date date not null
);

create table users_banned(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int references users.id,
    _from date not null,
    _to date not null,
    removed boolean default false,
    removed_date date default null
);

create table access_levels(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null
);

create table posts(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(100),
    user_id int references users.id,
    publish_date date not null,
    picture_name varchar(50) not null
);

create table posts_banned(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    post_id int references posts.id,
    _from date not null,
    _to date not null,
    removed boolean default false,
    removed_date date default null
);

create table post_likes(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    post_id int references posts.id,
    user_id int references users.id,
    date date not null
);

create table post_comments(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    post_id int references posts.id,
    user_id int references users.id,
    text varchar(500) not null,
    date date not null
);

create table post_comments_banned(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    comment_id int references post_comments.id,
    _from date not null,
    _to date not null,
    removed boolean default false,
    removed_date date default null
);


create table user_ip_adresses(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int references users.id,
    name varchar(15)
);

create table user_id_adresses_banned(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    ip_adress_id int references user_ip_addresses.id,
    _from date not null,
    _to date not null,
    removed boolean default false,
    removed_date date default null
);
```

and creating admin account:

```
insert into access_levels
(name)
VALUES
    ('CommonUser'),
    ('Admin');
    
insert into users
(name, password, access_level_id, creation_date)
VALUES
    ('root', '123321a', 2, curdate());
```

[To see code on GitHub](https://github.com/Daam10/MemeExchanger).

It is my first project on Spring MVC(used `Tomcat 7.0`) and I think I did many design and coding mistakes. Help me to find them, please.

I'll leave here some important files from my project:

AdminToolsController:

```
@Controller
public class AdminToolsController {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Date toForeverDate = new Date(3000, 1, 1); 
    
    @Autowired
    WebUtils webUtils;
    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;
    @Autowired
    IPostDAO postDAO;
    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = {
            "/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + adminToolsMenuUsersBanURL, 
            "/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + adminToolsMenuPostsBanURL,
            "/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + adminToolsMenuPostCommentsBanURL,
            "/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + adminToolsMenuIPAddressesBanURL}, 
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object entitiesBanManagement(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale) {
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null ||
            (redirectTo = webUtils.adminCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
            (redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
            (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }       
        
        
        if(request.getServletPath().endsWith(adminToolsMenuUsersBanURL)) {
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam, TypesOfEntity.USERS);
            request.setAttribute(typeOfIdentificatorParamName, TypesOfIdentificator.LOGIN);
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTitleAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("UsersBanManagement", null, locale));
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageIdentificatorNameAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("Login", null, locale));
        } else if(request.getServletPath().endsWith(adminToolsMenuPostsBanURL)) {
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam, TypesOfEntity.POSTS);
            request.setAttribute(typeOfIdentificatorParamName, TypesOfIdentificator.ID);
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTitleAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("PostsBanManagement", null, locale));
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageIdentificatorNameAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("PostID", null, locale));
        } else if(request.getServletPath().endsWith(adminToolsMenuPostCommentsBanURL)) {
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam, TypesOfEntity.POST_COMMENTS);
            request.setAttribute(typeOfIdentificatorParamName, TypesOfIdentificator.ID);
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTitleAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("PostCommentsBanManagement", null, locale));
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageIdentificatorNameAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("CommentID", null, locale));
        } else if(request.getServletPath().endsWith(adminToolsMenuIPAddressesBanURL)){
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam, TypesOfEntity.IP_ADDRESSES);
            request.setAttribute(typeOfIdentificatorParamName, TypesOfIdentificator.ID);
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTitleAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("IPAddressesBanManagement", null, locale));
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageIdentificatorNameAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("IPAddrID", null, locale)); // TODO: show user ip addresses before
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong URL");
        }
        return entitiesBanManagementPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + banURL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object ban(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale,
            @RequestParam(identificatorParamName) String identificator,
            @RequestParam(typeOfIdentificatorParamName) String typeOfIdentificator,
            @RequestParam(entitiesBanManagementPageToDateParam) String toDateString,
            @RequestParam(value = entitiesBanManagementPageForeverCheckboxParam, required = false) String foreverCheckbox,
            @RequestParam(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam) String typeOfEntity) throws ParseException {
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.adminCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        
        String banMenuURL = null;
        IBanner banner = null;
        IExistanceChecker existanceChecker = null;
        TypesOfEntity enumTypeOfEnity = null;
        TypesOfIdentificator enumTypeOfIdentificator = null;
        if(TypesOfEntity.contains(typeOfEntity)) {
            enumTypeOfEnity = TypesOfEntity.getByString(typeOfEntity);
            banner = chooseBanner(enumTypeOfEnity);
            banMenuURL = chooseBanMenuURL(enumTypeOfEnity);
        } else {
            return illegalEntityTypeRedirect(typeOfEntity, request, locale);
        }
        if(TypesOfIdentificator.contains(typeOfIdentificator)) {
            enumTypeOfIdentificator = TypesOfIdentificator.getByString(typeOfIdentificator);
            existanceChecker = chooseEntityExistanceChecker(enumTypeOfEnity, enumTypeOfIdentificator);
        } else {
            return illegalIdentificatorTypeRedirect(typeOfIdentificator, request, locale);
        }
        try {
            if(!existanceChecker.exists(identificator)) {
                return entityDoesntExistRedirect(banMenuURL, identificator, request, locale);
            }
            
            Date now = new Date();
            boolean forever = webUtils.getHTMLCheckboxValue(foreverCheckbox);
            if(forever) {
                banner.ban(now, toForeverDate, identificator);
            } else {
                try {
                    Date toDate = htmlDateFormater.parse(toDateString);
                    if(now.after(toDate)) {
                        return wrongToDateRedirect(banMenuURL, now, toDate, request, locale); // TODO: not generic message?
                    }
                    banner.ban(now, toDate, identificator);
                } catch(ParseException ex) {
                    return maybeDidntSetDateRedirect(banMenuURL, identificator, request, locale);
                }
            }
            return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + banMenuURL, true);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return illegalIdentificatorRedirect(banMenuURL, identificator, request, locale);
        }
        
        
    }

    @RequestMapping(value =  "/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + getBansURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object getBansUsingJSGet(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale,
            @RequestParam(countFromParamName) int from,
            @RequestParam(countToParamName) int to,
            @RequestParam(bansFirstIDFromFirstSetParamName) Integer idOfFirstBan,
            @RequestParam(identificatorParamName) String identificator,
            @RequestParam(typeOfIdentificatorParamName) String typeOfIdentificator,
            @RequestParam(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam) String typeOfEntity) {
        String loginFromCookies = webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request);
        if(webUtils.isLoggedUsingCookies(request) != LoginStatus.LOGGED) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("NotLogonMsg", new Object[] {loginFromCookies}, locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        if(!userDAO.isAdmin(loginFromCookies)) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("YouAreNotAdmin", null, locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        if(userDAO.isBannedUser(loginFromCookies)) {
            DateInterval banDateInterval = userDAO.getLastUserBanDateInterval(loginFromCookies);
            Date fromDate = null, toDate = null;
            if(banDateInterval != null) {
                fromDate = banDateInterval.getFromDate();
                toDate = banDateInterval.getToDate();
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("UserWithLoginBannedMsg", new Object[] {loginFromCookies, fromDate, toDate},  locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        if(userDAO.isBannedUserIPAddressByLogin(webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request))) {
            DateInterval banDateInterval = userDAO.getLastUserIPAddressBanDateInterval(loginFromCookies);
            IPAddress ipAddress = userDAO.getIPAddressByLogin(loginFromCookies);
            Date fromDate = null, toDate = null;
            if(banDateInterval != null) {
                fromDate = banDateInterval.getFromDate();
                toDate = banDateInterval.getToDate();
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("IPAddressBannedMsg", new Object[] {ipAddress == null ? null : ipAddress.getName(), fromDate, toDate},  locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        
        
        IBansGetter bansGetter = null;
        IExistanceChecker banExistanceChecker = null;
        TypesOfEntity enumTypeOfEnity = null;
        TypesOfIdentificator enumTypeOfIdentificator = null;
        if(TypesOfEntity.contains(typeOfEntity)) {
            enumTypeOfEnity = TypesOfEntity.getByString(typeOfEntity);
            bansGetter = chooseBansGetter(enumTypeOfEnity);
        } else {
            return illegalEntityTypeRedirect(typeOfEntity, request, locale);
        }
        if(TypesOfIdentificator.contains(typeOfIdentificator)) {
            enumTypeOfIdentificator = TypesOfIdentificator.getByString(typeOfIdentificator);
            banExistanceChecker = chooseEntityExistanceChecker(enumTypeOfEnity, enumTypeOfIdentificator);
        } else {
            return illegalIdentificatorTypeRedirect(typeOfIdentificator, request, locale);
        }
        
        try {
            if(!banExistanceChecker.exists(identificator)) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute(
                        failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, 
                        messageSource.getMessage("EntityDoesntExistsMsg", new Object[] {identificator}, locale)); 
                return failedPageName;
            }
            
            boolean isFirstSet = idOfFirstBan == null;
            int countOfNewBeforeFirst = 0;
            if(!isFirstSet) {
                countOfNewBeforeFirst = bansGetter.getBansCountBefore(idOfFirstBan);
            }
            System.out.println(identificator + " " + from + " " + to + " " + countOfNewBeforeFirst);
            List<Ban> bans = bansGetter.getBans(identificator, from + countOfNewBeforeFirst, to + countOfNewBeforeFirst);
            request.setAttribute(getBansPageBansAttrName, bans);
            request.setAttribute(getBansPageWhenSwitchedURLAttrName, changeBanStateURL);
            request.setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam, enumTypeOfEnity);
            request.setAttribute(isFirstSetAttrName, isFirstSet);
            return getBansPage;
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(
                    failedPageErrorMessageAttrName,
                    messageSource.getMessage(
                            "IllegalIdentificatorMsg", 
                            new Object[] {identificator}, 
                            locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/" + changeBanStateURL, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object changeBanState(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale,
            @RequestParam(value=getBansPageDoActiveParamName,required=false) String doActive,
            @RequestParam(identificatorParamName) String banIdentificator,
            @RequestParam(entitiesBanManagementPageTypeOfEntityParam) String typeOfEntity) {
        System.out.println(banIdentificator);
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.adminCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        
        String banMenuURL = null;
        IBanStateChanger banStateChanger = null;
        IExistanceChecker banExistanceChecker = null;
        if(TypesOfEntity.contains(typeOfEntity)) {
            TypesOfEntity enumTypeOfEnity = TypesOfEntity.getByString(typeOfEntity);
            banMenuURL = chooseBanMenuURL(enumTypeOfEnity);
            banExistanceChecker = chooseEntityBanExistanceChecker(enumTypeOfEnity, TypesOfIdentificator.ID);
            banStateChanger = chooseBanStateChanger(enumTypeOfEnity, TypesOfIdentificator.ID);
        } else {
            return illegalEntityTypeRedirect(typeOfEntity, request, locale);
        }
        
        try {
            if(!banExistanceChecker.exists(banIdentificator)) {
                return entityDoesntExistRedirect(banMenuURL, banIdentificator, request, locale);
            }
            boolean isActive = doActive == null ? true : false;
            int changedCount = banStateChanger.changeBanState(isActive, banIdentificator);
            if(changedCount != 1) {
                System.out.println("Changed " + changedCount + " bans instead of 1");
            }
            return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + banMenuURL, true);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return illegalIdentificatorRedirect(banMenuURL, banIdentificator, request, locale);
        }
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + getIPAddressByUserURL, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object getIPAddress(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale,
            @RequestParam(typeOfIdentificatorParamName) String typeOfIdentificator,
            @RequestParam(identificatorParamName) String identificator) {
        String loginFromCookies = webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request);
        if(webUtils.isLoggedUsingCookies(request) != LoginStatus.LOGGED) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("NotLogonMsg", new Object[] {loginFromCookies}, locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        if(!userDAO.isAdmin(loginFromCookies)) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("YouAreNotAdmin", null, locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        if(userDAO.isBannedUser(loginFromCookies)) {
            DateInterval banDateInterval = userDAO.getLastUserBanDateInterval(loginFromCookies);
            Date from = null, to = null;
            if(banDateInterval != null) {
                from = banDateInterval.getFromDate();
                to = banDateInterval.getToDate();
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("UserWithLoginBannedMsg", new Object[] {loginFromCookies, from, to},  locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        if(userDAO.isBannedUserIPAddressByLogin(webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request))) {
            DateInterval banDateInterval = userDAO.getLastUserIPAddressBanDateInterval(loginFromCookies);
            IPAddress ipAddress = userDAO.getIPAddressByLogin(loginFromCookies);
            Date from = null, to = null;
            if(banDateInterval != null) {
                from = banDateInterval.getFromDate();
                to = banDateInterval.getToDate();
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("IPAddressBannedMsg", new Object[] {ipAddress == null ? null : ipAddress.getName(), from, to},  locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        TypesOfIdentificator enumTypeOfIdentificator = null;
        IIPAddressGetter ipAddressGetter = null;
        if(TypesOfIdentificator.contains(typeOfIdentificator)) {
            enumTypeOfIdentificator = TypesOfIdentificator.getByString(typeOfIdentificator);
            ipAddressGetter = chooseByUserIPAddressGetter(enumTypeOfIdentificator);
        } else {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(
                    failedPageErrorMessageAttrName,
                    messageSource.getMessage(
                            "IllegalIdentificatorTypeMsg", 
                            new Object[] {
                                    typeOfIdentificator, 
                                    CommonUtils.getEnumeration(TypesOfIdentificator.getTypesOfIdentificatorList(), ", ")}, 
                            locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        
        try {
            request.setAttribute(getIPAddressPageIPAddressAttrName, ipAddressGetter.get(identificator));
            return getIPAddressPageName;
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(
                    failedPageErrorMessageAttrName,
                    messageSource.getMessage(
                            "IllegalIdentificatorMsg", 
                            new Object[] {identificator}, 
                            locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        
    }
    
    private IIPAddressGetter chooseByUserIPAddressGetter(TypesOfIdentificator enumTypeOfIdentificator) {
        switch(enumTypeOfIdentificator) {
        case LOGIN:
            return userDAO::getIPAddressByLogin;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        
    }

    private IExistanceChecker chooseEntityExistanceChecker(TypesOfEntity typeOfEntity, TypesOfIdentificator typeOfIdentificator) {
        switch(typeOfEntity) {
        case USERS:
            switch(typeOfIdentificator) {
            case LOGIN:
                return userDAO::existsUserByLogin;
            case ID:
                return (String identificator) -> userDAO.existsUserById(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal type of entity to ban");
            }
            
        case POSTS:
            return (String identificator) -> postDAO.existsPost(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case POST_COMMENTS:
            return (String identificator) -> postDAO.existsComment(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case IP_ADDRESSES:
            return (String identificator) -> userDAO.existsIPAddressById(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("illegal type of entity to ban");
        }
    }

    private String chooseBanMenuURL(TypesOfEntity typeOfEntity) {
        switch(typeOfEntity) {
        case USERS:
            return adminToolsMenuUsersBanURL;
        case POSTS:
            return adminToolsMenuPostsBanURL;
        case POST_COMMENTS:
            return adminToolsMenuPostCommentsBanURL;
        case IP_ADDRESSES:
            return adminToolsMenuIPAddressesBanURL;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("illegal type of entity to ban");
        }
    }
    
    private IBansGetter chooseBansGetter(TypesOfEntity typeOfEntity) {
        switch(typeOfEntity) {
        case USERS:
            return new IBansGetter() {
                @Override
                public List<Ban> getBans(String identificator, int from, int to) {
                    return userDAO.getUserBans(identificator, from, to);
                }
                @Override
                public int getBansCountBefore(int id) throws DataAccessException {
                    return userDAO.getUserBansCountBefore(id);
                }
            };
        case POSTS:
            return new IBansGetter() {
                @Override
                public List<Ban> getBans(String identificator, int from, int to) {
                    return postDAO.getPostBans(Integer.parseInt(identificator), from, to);
                }
                @Override
                public int getBansCountBefore(int id) throws DataAccessException {
                    return postDAO.getPostBansCountBefore(id);
                }
            };
        case POST_COMMENTS:
            return new IBansGetter() {
                @Override
                public List<Ban> getBans(String identificator, int from, int to) {
                    return postDAO.getCommentBans(Integer.parseInt(identificator), from, to);
                }
                @Override
                public int getBansCountBefore(int id) throws DataAccessException {
                    return postDAO.getCommentBansCountBefore(id);
                }
            };
        case IP_ADDRESSES:
            return new IBansGetter() {
                @Override
                public List<Ban> getBans(String identificator, int from, int to) {
                    return userDAO.getIPAddressBans(Integer.parseInt(identificator), from, to);
                }
                @Override
                public int getBansCountBefore(int id) throws DataAccessException {
                    return userDAO.getIPAddressBansCountBefore(id);
                }
            };
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal type of entity to ban");
        }
    }

    private IBanner chooseBanner(TypesOfEntity typeOfEntity) throws ParseException {
        switch(typeOfEntity) {
        case USERS:
            return userDAO::banUser;
        case POSTS:
            return (Date from, Date to, String identificator) -> postDAO.banPost(from, to, Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case POST_COMMENTS:
            return (Date from, Date to, String identificator) -> postDAO.banComment(from, to, Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case IP_ADDRESSES:
            return (Date from, Date to, String identificator) -> userDAO.banIPAddress(from, to, Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("illegal type of entity to ban");
        }
    }
    
    private IExistanceChecker chooseEntityBanExistanceChecker(TypesOfEntity typeOfEntity, TypesOfIdentificator typeOfIdentificator) {
        switch(typeOfEntity) {
        case USERS:
            return (String identificator) -> userDAO.existsUserBanById(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case POSTS:
            return (String identificator) -> postDAO.hasPostBan(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case POST_COMMENTS:
            return (String identificator) -> postDAO.hasCommentBan(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case IP_ADDRESSES:
            return (String identificator) -> userDAO.existsIPAddressBanById(Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("illegal type of entity to ban");
        }
    }
    
    private IBanStateChanger chooseBanStateChanger(TypesOfEntity typeOfEntity, TypesOfIdentificator typeOfIdentificator) {
        switch(typeOfEntity) {
        case USERS:
            return (boolean isActive, String identificator) -> userDAO.changeUserBanStateById(isActive, Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case POSTS:
            return (boolean isActive, String identificator) -> postDAO.changePostBanState(isActive, Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case POST_COMMENTS:
            return (boolean isActive, String identificator) -> postDAO.changeCommentBanState(isActive, Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        case IP_ADDRESSES:
            return (boolean isActive, String identificator) -> userDAO.changeIPAddressBanStateById(isActive, Integer.parseInt(identificator));
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("illegal type of entity to ban");
        }
    }

    private RedirectView maybeDidntSetDateRedirect(
            String adminToolURL,
            String login,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageMaybeDidntSetDateMsgAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("MaybeDidntSetDateMsg", null, locale));
        return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + adminToolURL, true);
    }

    private RedirectView wrongToDateRedirect(
            String adminToolURL,
            Date now,
            Date toDate,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageWrongToDateErrorMsgAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("WrongToDateErrorMsg", new Object[] {now, dbDateFormater.format(toDate)}, locale));
        return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + adminToolURL, true);
    }

    private RedirectView entityDoesntExistRedirect(
            String toolURL, 
            String identificator,
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            Locale locale) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(entitiesBanManagementPageEntityDoesntExistMsgAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("EntityDoesntExistsMsg", new Object[] {identificator}, locale)); 
        return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + toolURL, true);
    }
    
    private RedirectView illegalIdentificatorRedirect(
            String toolURL,
            String identificator,
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            Locale locale) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(
                adminToolsMenuPageIllegalEntityTypeMsgAttrName, // TODO: think about creating name-spaces - EntitiesBanManagement.* class f.e.
                messageSource.getMessage(
                        "IllegalIdentificatorMsg", 
                        new Object[] {identificator}, 
                        locale));
        return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + toolURL, true);
    }
    
    private RedirectView illegalIdentificatorTypeRedirect(
            String typeOfIdentificator, 
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            Locale locale) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(
                adminToolsMenuPageIllegalIdentificatorTypeMsgAttrName,
                messageSource.getMessage(
                        "IllegalIdentificatorTypeMsg", 
                        new Object[] {
                                typeOfIdentificator, 
                                CommonUtils.getEnumeration(TypesOfIdentificator.getTypesOfIdentificatorList(), ", ")}, 
                        locale));
        return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL, true);
    }
    
    private RedirectView illegalEntityTypeRedirect(
            String typeOfEntity,
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            Locale locale) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(
                adminToolsMenuPageIllegalEntityTypeMsgAttrName,
                messageSource.getMessage(
                        "IllegalEntityTypeMsg", 
                        new Object[] {
                                typeOfEntity, 
                                CommonUtils.getEnumeration(TypesOfEntity.getTypesOfEntityList(), ", ")}, 
                        locale));
        return new RedirectView("/" + adminToolsMenuURL, true);
    }
}
```

DefaultController:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {
    
    @Autowired
    WebUtils webUtils;
    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;
    @Autowired
    IPostDAO postDAO;
    @Autowired
    IFileChecker fileChecker;
    @Autowired
    IPostTitleChecker postTitleChecker;
    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + mainURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object main(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) {
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        request.setAttribute(isAdminAttrName, userDAO.isAdmin(webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request)));
        return mainPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + createPostURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object createPost(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) {
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null || 
                (redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        int countOfPostsToday = postDAO.countOfPostsToday(webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request));
        if(countOfPostsToday >= MAX_POSTS_COUNT_PER_DAY) { 
            if(request.getSession().getAttribute(createPostPageTooManyPostsPerDayMsgAttrName) == null) { // if didn't redirected from createPost_postForm with this error
                request.getSession().setAttribute(
                        createPostPageTooManyPostsPerDayMsgAttrName, 
                        messageSource.getMessage(
                                "TooManyPostsPerDayMsg", 
                                new Object[] {webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request), MAX_POSTS_COUNT_PER_DAY},
                        locale));
            }
            
        }
        return createPostPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + createPostURL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object createPost_postForm(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(createPostPageTitleParamName) String title,
            @RequestParam(createPostPageFileParamName) CommonsMultipartFile file, 
            Locale locale) throws IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        List<String> errors;
        boolean hasErrors = false;
        if(!(errors = fileChecker.getErrorsBeforeGetting(file, locale)).isEmpty()) {
            hasErrors = true;
            errors.forEach(System.out::println);
            session.setAttribute(createPostPageFileBeforeInsertErrorsAttrName, errors);
        }
        if(!(errors = postTitleChecker.getErrors(title, locale)).isEmpty()) {
            hasErrors = true;
            errors.forEach(System.out::println);
            session.setAttribute(createPostPageTitleErrorsAttrName, errors);
        }
        int countOfPostsToday = postDAO.countOfPostsToday(webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request));
        if(countOfPostsToday >= MAX_POSTS_COUNT_PER_DAY) {
            hasErrors = true;
            session.setAttribute(
                    createPostPageTooManyPostsPerDayMsgAttrName, 
                    messageSource.getMessage(
                            "TooManyPostsPerDayMsg", 
                            new Object[] {webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request), MAX_POSTS_COUNT_PER_DAY},
                    locale));
        }
        if(hasErrors) {
            return new RedirectView("/" + createPostURL, true);
        }
        String insertedFileName = postDAO.insertFile(file, locale);
        if(!(errors = fileChecker.getErrorsAfterGetting(insertedFileName, locale)).isEmpty()) {
            errors.forEach(System.out::println);
            session.setAttribute(createPostPageFileAfterInsertErrorsAttrName, errors);
            return new RedirectView("/" + createPostURL, true);
        }
        System.out.println(insertedFileName);
        postDAO.insertRecord(webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request), title, insertedFileName);
        return new RedirectView("/" + createPostURL, true);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + feedURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object feed(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        return feedPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + getFeedURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object getFeed(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(countFromParamName) int from,
            @RequestParam(countToParamName) int to,
            @RequestParam(postsFirstIDFromFirstSetParamName) Integer idOfFirst) throws IOException {
        if(webUtils.loggedCheck(request) != null) {
            return null; // TODO: write smth in answer?
        }
        boolean isFirstSet = idOfFirst == null;
        int countOfNewBeforeFirst = 0;
        if(!isFirstSet) {
            countOfNewBeforeFirst = postDAO.getCountPostsBefore(idOfFirst);
        }
        List<FeedPostWithBanInfo> feedPostsWithBanInfo = postDAO.getFreshPostsWithBiggestBanInfo(from + countOfNewBeforeFirst, to + countOfNewBeforeFirst);
        feedPostsWithBanInfo.forEach(System.out::println);
        request.setAttribute(feedPostsWithBanInfoAttrName, feedPostsWithBanInfo);
        request.setAttribute(isFirstSetAttrName, isFirstSet);
        String loginFromCookies = webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request);
        request.setAttribute(getFeedPageCanLeaveCommentsAttrName, canLeaveComments(loginFromCookies));
        request.setAttribute(loginAttrName, loginFromCookies);
        return getFeedPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + createCommentURL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object createComment(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(getFeedTextOfCommentParamName) String text,
            @RequestParam(postIDParamName) int postID) {
        String loginFromCookies = webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request);
        if(webUtils.isLoggedUsingCookies(request) != LoginStatus.LOGGED ||
                userDAO.isBannedUser(loginFromCookies)  ||
                userDAO.isBannedUserIPAddressByLogin(loginFromCookies)) {
            return "error - banned or not logged"; // TODO: to return smth?
        }
        
        if(text.length() > MAX_COMMENT_LENGTH || text.length() < MIN_COMMENT_LENGTH) {
            return "error - comment has illegal length - > " + MAX_COMMENT_LENGTH + " or < " + MIN_COMMENT_LENGTH;
        }
        if(!postDAO.existsPost(postID) || postDAO.isPostBanned(postID)) {
            return "error - post doesn't exist or banned";
        }
        if(postDAO.getCommentsCountPerDay(loginFromCookies) > MAX_COMMENTS_COUNT_PER_DAY) {
            return "too many comments per day";
        }
        
        int countCreated = postDAO.createComment(postID, loginFromCookies, text);
        if(countCreated == 0) {
            return "not created";
        }
        return "ok";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + imgsURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getImg(@RequestParam(imgNameParamName) String name, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) throws IOException {
        if(webUtils.loggedCheck(request) != null ||
                webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale) != null) {
            return; // TODO: to return smth?
        }
        File file = new File(picturesDirectiory + File.separatorChar + name);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println(name);
            response.sendError(404, messageSource.getMessage("ImgNotFoundMsg", new Object[] {name}, locale));
            return;
        }
        
        String postfix = name.split("\\.")[1];
        if(!PossibleIMGsSuffixes.contains(postfix.toLowerCase())) {
            response.sendError(500, messageSource.getMessage("InvalidFileTypeOnServerMsg", new Object[] {name}, locale));
        }
        response.setContentType("image/" + postfix);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/" + getCommentsURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object getComments(HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale,
            @RequestParam(countFromParamName) int from,
            @RequestParam(countToParamName) int to,
            @RequestParam(commentsFirstIDFromFirstSetParamName) Integer idOfFirstComment,
            @RequestParam(postIDParamName) int postID) {
        String loginFromCookies = webUtils.getLoginFromCookies(request);
        if(webUtils.isLoggedUsingCookies(request) != LoginStatus.LOGGED) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(failedPageErrorMessageAttrName, messageSource.getMessage("NotLogonMsg", new Object[] {loginFromCookies}, locale));
            return failedPageName;
        }
        
        
        boolean isFirstSet = idOfFirstComment == null;
        
        int countOfNewBeforeFirst = 0;
        if(!isFirstSet) {
            countOfNewBeforeFirst = postDAO.getCommentsCountUnderPostBefore(idOfFirstComment);
        }
        List<PostCommentWithBanInfo> comments = postDAO.getFreshCommentsWithBiggestBanInfo(postID, from + countOfNewBeforeFirst, to + countOfNewBeforeFirst);
        request.setAttribute(getCommentsPageCommentsAttrName, comments);
        request.setAttribute(isFirstSetAttrName, isFirstSet);
        request.setAttribute(postIDAttrName, postID);
        System.out.println(from + " " + to + " " + countOfNewBeforeFirst);
        return getCommentsPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + adminToolsMenuURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object adminToolsMenu(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) {
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.loggedCheck(request)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.adminCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null ||
                (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        return adminToolsMenuPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/" + failedURL)
    public Object failed(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return failedPageName;
    }
    
    boolean canLeaveComments(String login) {
        return !userDAO.isBannedUser(login) && !userDAO.isBannedUserIPAddressByLogin(login);
    }
}
```

EnterController:

```
@Controller
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class EnterController {
    
    @Autowired
    WebUtils webUtils;
    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;
    @Autowired
    IUserChecker userChecker;
    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + rootURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object root(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(webUtils.isLoggedUsingCookies(request) != LoginStatus.LOGGED) { // to do ban checks
            return rootPageName;
        }
        return new RedirectView(mainURL, true);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + loginURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return loginPageName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + loginURL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object login_loginForm(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpSession model,
            @RequestParam(loginPageLoginParamName) String login, 
            @RequestParam(loginPagePasswordParamName) String password, 
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Locale locale) {
        if(userDAO.isWrong(login, password)) {
            model.setAttribute(
                    loginPageWrongLoginOrPasswordMsgAttrName, 
                    messageSource.getMessage("WrongLoginOrPasswordMsg", null, locale));
            return loginPageName;
        }
        RedirectView redirectTo;
        if((redirectTo = webUtils.userBanCheck(login, request, messageSource, locale)) != null || 
                (redirectTo = webUtils.ipAddressBanCheck(login, request, messageSource, locale)) != null) {
            return redirectTo;
        }
        webUtils.putUserIntoCookies(response, login, password, secondsToSaveCookie);
        return new RedirectView(mainURL, true);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + registrationURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object registration(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return registrationPageName;
    }
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + registrationURL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object registration_registationForm(
            @RequestParam(registrationPageLoginParamName) String login, 
            @RequestParam(registrationPagePasswordParamName) String password, 
            HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale) {
        if(userDAO.existsUserByLogin(login)) {
            request.setAttribute(
                    registrationPageLoginAlreadyExistsMsgAttrName, 
                    messageSource.getMessage("LoginAlreadyExistsMsg", null, locale));
            return registrationPageName;
        }
        List<String> errors;
        if(!(errors = userChecker.getLoginErrors(login, locale)).isEmpty()) {
            errors.forEach(System.out::println);
            request.setAttribute(registrationPageLoginErrorsAttrName, errors);
            return registrationPageName;
        }
        if(!(errors = userChecker.getPasswordErrors(password, locale)).isEmpty()) {
            errors.forEach(System.out::println);
            request.setAttribute(registrationPagePasswordErrorsAttrName, errors);
            return registrationPageName;
        }
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        if(userDAO.getCountOfAccountsOfAddr(ipAddress) > MAX_ACCOUNT_COUNT_PER_ADDR) {
            request.setAttribute(
                    registrationPageTooManyAccountsMsgAttrName, 
                    messageSource.getMessage("TooManyAccountsMsg", new Object[] {MAX_ACCOUNT_COUNT_PER_ADDR}, locale));
            return registrationPageName;
        }
        
        webUtils.putUserIntoCookies(response, login, password, secondsToSaveCookie);
        
        userDAO.insertUser(login, password);
        userDAO.insertIPAddress(login, ipAddress);
        return new RedirectView(mainURL, true);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/" + logoutURL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RedirectView logout(HttpServletResponse response) {
        webUtils.deleteCookies(new String[] {loginCookieName, passwordCookieName}, response);
        return new RedirectView(rootURL, true);
    }
}
```

MySQLPostDAO:

```
@Component
public class MySQLPostDAO implements IPostDAO {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;
    
    @Autowired
    public MySQLPostDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String insertFile(CommonsMultipartFile file, Locale locale) throws IOException, IllegalStateException, EmptyFileException { // TODO: think about it. It doesn't have any relation to MySQL(!)PostDAO
        if(!file.isEmpty()) {
            File fileToUpload = null;
            String[] splittedByDots = file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.");
            String fileName = CommonUtils.connectTo(splittedByDots, splittedByDots.length - 1);
            String fileExtension = "." + splittedByDots[splittedByDots.length - 1].toLowerCase(); // SHOULD BE SAVED IN LOWER CASE!
            boolean foundPlace = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if(!(fileToUpload = new File(picturesDirectiory + File.separatorChar + fileName + Integer.toString(i) + fileExtension)).exists()) {
                    foundPlace = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!foundPlace) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(messageSource.getMessage("TooManyFilesWithNameMsg", new Object[] {MAX_FILES_WITH_SAME_NAME_COUNT}, locale));
            }
            
            fileToUpload.createNewFile();
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToUpload));
            out.write(file.getBytes());
            out.close();
            
            return fileToUpload.getName();
        }
        throw new EmptyFileException(messageSource.getMessage("EmptyFileMsg", new Object[] {file.getOriginalFilename()}, locale));
    }

    @Override
    public void insertRecord(String login, String title, String filePath) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4}) VALUES (?, (SELECT {5} FROM {6} WHERE {7} = ?), curdate(), ?);", 
                postsTableName, 
                postsTableTitleFieldName, 
                postsTableUserIDFieldName,
                postsTablePublishDateFieldName,
                postsTablePictureNameFieldName,
                usersTableIDFieldName,
                usersTableName,
                usersTableLoginFieldName); // TODO: to remember method with names, not numbers
        jdbcTemplate.update(query.toString(), new Object[] {title, login, filePath});
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedPost> getFreshPosts(int countGot, int countToGet) throws DataAccessException{
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT {1}, {2}, (SELECT {3} FROM {4} WHERE {5} = {0}.{6}), {7}, {8} FROM {0} ORDER BY {7} DESC, {1} DESC LIMIT ?, ?",
                postsTableName,
                postsTableIDFieldName,
                postsTableTitleFieldName,
                
                usersTableLoginFieldName,
                usersTableName,
                usersTableIDFieldName,
                postsTableUserIDFieldName,
                
                postsTablePublishDateFieldName,
                postsTablePictureNameFieldName);
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] {countGot, countToGet}, new PostMapper());
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            return new ArrayList<FeedPost>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedPostWithBanInfo> getFreshPostsWithBiggestBanInfo(int countGot, int countToGet) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                //TODO: bad getting 
                "SELECT {0}.{3}, {0}.{9}, (SELECT {11} FROM {12} WHERE {13} = {0}.{10}) as {11}, {0}.{1}, {14}, ifnull({2}.{5}, true) as {5}, {2}.{6}, {2}.{7} "
                + "FROM (SELECT * FROM {0} ORDER BY {1} DESC, {3} DESC LIMIT ?, ?) as {0} "
                + "LEFT JOIN (SELECT {5}, {6}, {7}, {4} FROM {2} as pb1 WHERE {8} = "
                + "(SELECT {8} FROM {2} as pb2 WHERE {6} <= curdate() AND {7} >= curdate() AND pb1.{4} = pb2.{4} AND {7} = "
                + "(SELECT MAX({7}) FROM {2} as pb3 WHERE {6} <= curdate() AND {7} >= curdate() AND pb3.{4} = pb2.{4}) LIMIT 1)) as {2} "
                + "ON {2}.{4} = {0}.{3} ORDER BY {0}.{1} DESC, {0}.{3} DESC",
                postsTableName,
                postsTablePublishDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableName,
                postsTableIDFieldName,
                postsBannedTablePostIDFieldName,
                postsBannedTableRemovedFieldName,
                postsBannedTableFromDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableToDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableIDFieldName,
                
                postsTableTitleFieldName,
                postsTableUserIDFieldName,
                usersTableLoginFieldName,
                usersTableName,
                usersTableIDFieldName,
                postsTablePictureNameFieldName);
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] {countGot, countToGet}, new PostWithBanInfoMapper());
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            return new ArrayList<FeedPostWithBanInfo>();
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    @Override
    public int changePostBanState(boolean isActive, int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "UPDATE {0} SET {1} = " + (isActive ? "true" : "false") + ", {2} = " + (isActive ? "curdate()" : "null") + " WHERE {3} = ?",
                postsBannedTableName,
                postsBannedTableRemovedFieldName,
                postsBannedTableRemovedDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableIDFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {id});
    }
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    @Override
    public int changeCommentBanState(boolean isActive, int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "UPDATE {0} SET {1} = " + (isActive ? "true" : "false") + ", {2} = " + (isActive ? "curdate()" : "null") + " WHERE {3} = ?",
                postCommentsBannedTableName,
                postCommentsBannedTableRemovedFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableRemovedDateFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableIDFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {id});
    }

    @Override
    public boolean existsPost(int id) throws DataAccessException, IllegalStateException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = ?", 
                postsTableName, 
                postsTableIDFieldName);
        
        int accountsCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {id}, Integer.class);
        if(accountsCount == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if(accountsCount == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("DB unique id error"); // don't need to be localized
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean existsComment(int id) throws DataAccessException, IllegalStateException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = ?", 
                postCommentsTableName, 
                postCommentsTableIDFieldName);
        
        int accountsCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {id}, Integer.class);
        if(accountsCount == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if(accountsCount == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("DB unique id error"); // don't need to be localized
    }

    @Override
    public List<Ban> getPostBans(int id, int from, int to) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} FROM {5} WHERE {6} = ? ORDER BY {1} DESC, {0} DESC LIMIT ?, ?",
                postsBannedTableIDFieldName,
                postsBannedTableFromDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableToDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableRemovedFieldName,
                postsBannedTableRemovedDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableName,
                postsBannedTablePostIDFieldName);
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] {id, from, to} , new BanMapperForPost());
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            return new ArrayList<Ban>();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Ban> getCommentBans(int id, int from, int to) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} FROM {5} WHERE {6} = ? ORDER BY {1} DESC, {0} DESC LIMIT ?, ?",
                postCommentsBannedTableIDFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableFromDateFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableToDateFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableRemovedFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableRemovedDateFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableName,
                postCommentsBannedTableCommentIDFieldName);
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] {id, from, to} , new BanMapperForPost());
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            return new ArrayList<Ban>();
        }
    }



    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    @Override
    public int banPost(Date from, Date to, int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                postsBannedTableName,
                postsBannedTablePostIDFieldName,
                postsBannedTableFromDateFieldName,
                postsBannedTableToDateFieldName);
        int countBanned = jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {id, dbDateFormater.format(from), dbDateFormater.format(to)});
        return countBanned;
    }
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    @Override
    public int banComment(Date from, Date to, int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                postCommentsBannedTableName,
                postCommentsBannedTableCommentIDFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableFromDateFieldName,
                postCommentsBannedTableToDateFieldName);
        int countBanned = jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {id, dbDateFormater.format(from), dbDateFormater.format(to)});
        return countBanned;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPostBan(int id) throws DataAccessException{
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = ?",
                postsBannedTableName,
                postsBannedTableIDFieldName);
        int bansCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {id}, Integer.class);
        if(bansCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    @Override
    public boolean hasCommentBan(int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = ?",
                postCommentsBannedTableName,
                postCommentsBannedTableIDFieldName);
        int bansCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {id}, Integer.class);
        if(bansCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isPostBanned(int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = ? AND {2} = false",
                postsBannedTableName,
                postsBannedTablePostIDFieldName,
                postsBannedTableRemovedFieldName);
        return 0 < jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {id}, Integer.class) ;
    }

    @Override
    public int countOfPostsToday(String login) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = curdate() AND {2} = (SELECT {3} FROM {4} WHERE {5} = ?)",
                postsTableName,
                postsTablePublishDateFieldName,
                postsTableUserIDFieldName,
                usersTableIDFieldName,
                usersTableName,
                usersTableLoginFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {login}, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCountPostsBefore(int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} > ?", // id should indicate order of publish!
                postsTableName,
                postsBannedTableIDFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {id}, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPostBansCountBefore(int banId) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} > ?",
                postsBannedTableName,
                postsBannedTableIDFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {banId}, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCommentBansCountBefore(int banId) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} > ?",
                postCommentsBannedTableName,
                postCommentsBannedTableIDFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {banId}, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCommentsCountUnderPostBefore(int idOfComment) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = (SELECT {1} FROM {0} WHERE {2} = ?) AND {1} > ?",
                postCommentsTableName,
                postCommentsTablePostIDFieldName,
                postCommentsTableIDFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {idOfComment, idOfComment}, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPostIDByCommentID(int id) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = ?",
                postCommentsTablePostIDFieldName,
                postCommentsTableName,
                postCommentsTableIDFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {id}, Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PostCommentWithBanInfo> getFreshCommentsWithBiggestBanInfo(int postID, int countGot, int countToGet) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                //TODO: bad getting
                "SELECT pc1.{1}, pc1.{2}, (SELECT {8} FROM {6} WHERE {7} = pc1.{3}) as {8}, pc1.{4}, "
                + "ifnull(cb1.{10}, true) as {10}, cb1.{11}, cb1.{12} "
                + "FROM (SELECT {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} FROM {0} WHERE {5} = ? ORDER BY {4}, {1} LIMIT ?, ?) as pc1 "
                + "LEFT JOIN (SELECT {10}, {11}, {12}, {13} FROM {9} as cb1 WHERE {11} <= curdate() AND {12} >= curdate() "
                + "AND {12} = (SELECT MAX({12}) FROM {9} as cb2 WHERE {11} <= curdate() AND {12} >= curdate() AND cb1.{13} = cb2.{13}) LIMIT 1) as cb1 "
                + "ON pc1.{1} = cb1.{13} ORDER BY pc1.{4}, pc1.{1}",
                postCommentsTableName, // 0
                postCommentsTableIDFieldName, // 1
                postCommentsTableTextFieldName, // 2
                postCommentsTableUserIDFieldName, // 3
                postCommentsTableDateFieldName, // 4
                postCommentsTablePostIDFieldName, // 5
                
                usersTableName, // 6
                usersTableIDFieldName, // 7
                usersTableLoginFieldName, // 8
                
                postCommentsBannedTableName, // 9
                postCommentsBannedTableRemovedFieldName, // 10
                postCommentsBannedTableFromDateFieldName, // 11
                postCommentsBannedTableToDateFieldName, // 12
                postCommentsBannedTableCommentIDFieldName // 13
                );
        
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] {postID, countGot, countToGet}, new PostCommentWithBanInfoMapper());
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            return new ArrayList<PostCommentWithBanInfo>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int createComment(int postID, String login, String text) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4}) VALUES (?, (SELECT {5} FROM {6} WHERE {7} = ?), ?, curdate())", 
                postCommentsTableName,
                postCommentsTablePostIDFieldName,
                postCommentsTableUserIDFieldName,
                postCommentsTableTextFieldName,
                postCommentsTableDateFieldName,
                
                usersTableIDFieldName,
                usersTableName,
                usersTableLoginFieldName);
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {postID, login, text});
    }

    @Override
    public int getCommentsCountPerDay(String login) throws DataAccessException {
        String query = MessageFormat.format(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = curdate() AND {2} = (SELECT {3} FROM {4} WHERE {5} = ?)",
                postCommentsTableName,
                postCommentsTableDateFieldName,
                postCommentsTableUserIDFieldName,
                
                usersTableIDFieldName,
                usersTableName,
                usersTableLoginFieldName); 
        return  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {login}, Integer.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### A comment on the DDL

Despite this using MySQL (which would never be my first choice), the schema seems pretty sane; good job. This surprised me:

```
removed_date date default null
```

but then, reading the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html), MySQL does a nonsensical thing by default and uses the "zero" value for a date as its default; so what you've done is correct.

For these two columns:

```
_from date not null,
_to date not null,
```

If you didn't want an underscore, you can instead use [quote escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table).

For columns like these:

```
removed boolean default false,
```

you should consider making them `not null`.

### User table

```
insert into users
(name, password, access_level_id, creation_date)
VALUES
    ('root', '123321a', 2, curdate());
```

First of all, you should be able to make the current date the default for `creation_date` so that you don't actually need to specify it in the `insert`. Second and certainly the most concerning thing I see in all of this code is what appears to be a plain-text password. Never, ever, ever, ever put a plaintext password in a database. I implore to you have a careful read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270526/how-do-you-securely-store-a-users-password-and-salt-in-mysql ,  or similar articles, noting that some suggest MD5 which should be avoided due to cryptographic weakness. It is crucial to hash and salt passwords.

Comment: Do you have any remarks about queries(`MySQLPostDAO`, `MySQLUserDAO`)?

Comment: No, because they aren't included in the body of the question. If you want them to be reviewed they should be included in-line rather than linked to a repository.

Comment: I cannot include all my code in question, because my code has too many symbols. I tried. But I noticed a limitation when I finished including `DAOs` package. I cannot include all code physically.

Comment: I ll try to include only important files, but i think, that it will be bad without others

Comment: Files have been added to the question on request.

Comment: What about making the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) barely readable for laymen and then linking to it? ;)